# Solve y′−∫x0y(t)dt=2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How i solve this?

I have not idea how to approach this differential equation.

y′−∫x0y(t)dt=2

I get the probably familiar DE:
y′′−y=0.

please someone can solve this exercise

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333954/solve-y-int-0xytdt-2?rq=1 looks like OP might be referring to this same problem

Comment: Still haven't used every function on mathstackexchange but I just used the flag button. Thanks @Moo